# Checking username availability with jQuery and MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a user name textbox that I want to check if it is available while the user types. I have set up the jQuery as such:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#UserName_" + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PersonId))).bind("keypress", function () {
        if($(this).val().length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Student/CheckUserName",
                type: "GET",
                data: { userName: $("#UserName_"  + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PersonId))).val() },
                success: function (data, responseStatus, jQXHR) {
                    $("#WRAPPERDIVID_" + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PersonId))).html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And the page up as such:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "UserName_" + Model.PersonId } })
    <div id="WRAPPERDIVID_@Model.PersonId"></div>
</div>
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
 // GET: Student/CheckUserName
    public async Task<String> CheckUserName(String username)
    {
        var exists = await db.Students.Where(u => u.UserName == username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (exists == null) { return "That User Name is available!"; }
        return "That User Name is NOT available!";
    }
```

Everything works just fine - or so it seems. I want the user name to be at least 6 characters so I originally set to to start checking after 5 characters, but I was seeing odd results, so I changed it to 0. Still getting odd results and I think it has to do with binding to the "keypress" event, but I'm not sure.

What happens is it will only check the six character password after the user has typed the 7th character - either a character or a space.

So if I type in a password that is not available like "candy4", it won't tell me that it isn't available until I type something like "candy45", which itself might be available, but the message will say it is not because it is responding to "candy4" not being available. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why are you using `$("#UserName_" + @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.PersonId)))` instead of just `$('#UserName')` (and removing the `@id = "UserName_" + Model.PersonId`? MVC already comes with all this builtin - refer [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm an idiot. I just changed "keypress" to "keyup" and it works as I expect it to. Makes sense after I thought about it while writing this question - I guess that's all it takes sometimes!